# Parse array of numbers between emptylines

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec

I'm trying to make a parser to scan arrays of numbers separated by empty lines in a text file.

```
1   235 623 684
2   871 699 557
3   918 686 49
4   53  564 906


1   154
2   321
3   519

1   235 623 684
2   871 699 557
3   918 686 49
```

Here is the full [text file](http://www.2shared.com/document/3Kv2TlV6/test_listtst.html)

I wrote the following parser with `parsec` :

```
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec

emptyLine = do
  spaces
  newline

emptyLines = many1 emptyLine

data1 = do
  dat <- many1 digit
  return (dat)

datan = do
  many1 (oneOf " \t")
  dat <- many1 digit
  return (dat)

dataline  = do
  dat1 <- data1
  dat2 <- many datan
  many (oneOf " \t")
  newline
  return (dat1:dat2)

parseSeries = do 
    dat <- many1 dataline  
    return dat

parseParag =  try parseSeries

parseListing = do 
    --cont <- parseSeries `sepBy` emptyLines
    cont <- between emptyLines emptyLines parseSeries
    eof
    return cont

main = do
    fichier <- readFile ("test_listtst.txt")
    case parse parseListing "(test)" fichier of
            Left error -> do putStrLn "!!! Error !!!"
                             print error
            Right serie -> do  
                                mapM_ print serie
```

but it fails with the following error :

```
!!! Error !!!
"(test)" (line 6, column 1):
unexpected "1"
expecting space or new-line
```

and I don't understand why.

**Do you have any idea of what's wrong with my parser ?**

**Do you have an example on how to parse a structured bunch of data separated by empty lines ?**

Comment: Please add your imports...

Comment: I added the import file

Comment: I meant: add the `import ...` lines in your Haskell source file. As is, your code snippet is not self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Do you have any idea of what's wrong with my parser ?**

A few things:

1. As other answerers have already pointed out, the `spaces` parser is designed to consume a sequence of characters that satisfy `Data.Char.isSpace`; the newline (`'\n'`) is such a character. Therefore, your `emptyLine` parser always fails, because `newline` expects a newline character that has already been consumed.
2. You probably shouldn't use the `newline` parser in your "line" parsers anyway, because those parsers will fail on the last line of the file if the latter doesn't end with a newline.
3. Why not use parsec 3 (`Text.Parsec.*`) rather than parsec 2 (`Text.ParserCombinators.*`)?
4. Why not parse the numbers as `Integer`s or `Int`s as you go, rather than keep them as `String`s?
5. Personal preference, but you rely too much on the `do` notation for my taste, to the detriment of readability. For instance,

   ```
   data1 = do
     dat <- many1 digit
     return (dat)
   ```

   can be simplified to

   ```
   data1 = many1 digit
   ```
6. You would do well to add a type signature to all your top-level bindings.
7. Be consistent in how you name your parsers: why "parseListing" instead of simply "listing"?
8. Have you considered using a different type of input stream (e.g. `Text`) for better performance?

> **Do you have an example on how to parse a structured bunch of data separated by empty lines ?**

Below is a much simplified version of the kind of parser you want. Note that the input is not supposed to begin with (but may end with) empty lines, and "data lines" are not supposed to contain leading *spaces*, but may contain trailing *spaces* (in the sense of the `spaces` parser).

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Char ( isSpace )
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String ( Parser )

eolChar :: Char
eolChar = '\n'

eol :: Parser Char
eol = char eolChar

whitespace :: Parser String
whitespace = many $ satisfy $ \c -> isSpace c && c /= eolChar

emptyLine :: Parser String
emptyLine = whitespace

emptyLines :: Parser [String]
emptyLines = sepEndBy1 emptyLine eol

cell :: Parser Integer
cell = read <$> many1 digit

dataLine :: Parser [Integer]
dataLine = sepEndBy1 cell whitespace
--             ^
-- replace by endBy1 if no trailing whitespace is allowed in a "data line"

dataLines :: Parser [[Integer]]
dataLines = sepEndBy1 dataLine eol

listing :: Parser [[[Integer]]]
listing = sepEndBy dataLines emptyLines

main :: IO ()
main = do
    fichier <- readFile ("test_listtst.txt")
    case parse listing "(test)" fichier of
        Left error  -> putStrLn "!!! Error !!!"
        Right serie -> mapM_ print serie
```

Test:

```
λ> main
[[1,235,623,684],[2,871,699,557],[3,918,686,49],[4,53,564,906]]
[[1,154],[2,321],[3,519]]
[[1,235,623,684],[2,871,699,557],[3,918,686,49]]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `spaces` in `emptyLine` is consuming the `'\n'`, and then `newline` has no `'\n'` to parse. You can write it as:

```
emptyLine = do
  skipMany $ satisfy (\c -> isSpace c && c /= '\n')
  newline
```

And you should change `parseListing` to:

```
parseListing = do 
    cont <- parseSeries `sepEndBy` emptyLines
    eof
    return cont
```

I think `sepEndBy` is better than `sepBy`, because it will skip any new lines that you may have at the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

`spaces` includes new lines, and so `spaces >> newline` always fails which implies that the `emptyLine` parser will always fail.

I've had luck with these definitions of `parseSeries` and `parseListing`:

```
parseSeries = do
  s <- many1 dataline
  spaces                  -- eat trailing whitespace
  return s

parseListing = do
  spaces                  -- ignore leading whitespace
  ss <- many parseSeries  -- begin parseSeries at non-whitespace
  eof
  return ss
```

The idea is that a parser always eats the whitespace following it.
This approach also handles empty files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which allows you to stream in the data and process each block as it is identified:

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Monad

-- toBlocks - convert a list of lines into a list of blocks
toBlocks :: [String] -> [[[String]]]
toBlocks []  = []
toBlocks theLines =
  let (block,rest) = break isBlank theLines
      next = dropWhile isBlank rest
  in  if null block
        then toBlocks next
        else [ words x | x <- block ] : toBlocks next
  where isBlank str = all isSpace str

main' path = do
  content <- readFile path
  forM_ (toBlocks (lines content)) $ print
```

Parsec has to read in the entire file before it gives you the list of blocks which might be a problem if your input file is large.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact problem but my experience with parsing "line oriented" file with parsec is  : don't use parsec ( or at least not this way).

I mean the problem is you want somehow to strip the blanks (spaces and newline) between numbers (on the same line) but still being aware of them when needed.
It's really hard to do in one step (which is what you are trying to do).
It's probably doable adding lookahead but it's really messy (and to be honest I never managed to make it work).

The easiest way is to parse lines on the first step (which allow you to detect empty lines) and then parse each line separately.

To do that, you don't need parsec at all and can do it just using `lines` and `words`. However, doing this, you are losing the ability to backtrack.

There is probably a way to "mulitple steps" parsing using parsec and it's tokenizer (but I haven't find any useful doc about how to use parsec tokenizer).

Comment: *[...] don't use parsec [...]* I respectfully disagree. The parser needed here isn't much different from that in [Chapter 16 of *Real World Haskell*](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html), which `parsec` handles very well.

Comment: There is a small difference, which is all the lines are similar in the RHW example which makes it easy to parse using parsec. The problem here is to parse the empty lines but not skip them. I add similar problems in the past and end-up ditching parsec. However I might be wrong and maybe the OP problem is simpler than mine and is easy to solve. Or maybe my problem was easier than I though. I'm curious to see working solution for the OP problem. I'll probably be able to translate it to mines.

Comment: I think the real problem with using parsec is that it has to read the entire file in order for the parse to be successful - i.e. you can't process elements as they are identified.

Comment: @user5402 attoparsec supports incremental parsing, though.